# CSS class not applying in specific scenario

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a portfolio website, and for the works section I'm using Javascript to navigate through the different categories so that later I might get fancy with some smooth navigation animations.

My navigation menu is on the left, and I have a table set up to display the artwork and accompanying descriptions with a div class that pushes the left margin just past the menu and has the width fit to the browser window when you re-size. I also have it horizontally scrolling.

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yo8JE.jpg)

**My problem** is that while the div class wrapped around the table works on the portfolio landing page, it doesn't seem to work when I click one of the navigation items. The class I applied to the table itself seems to have no problems, but there is no scroll or margin, causing the table to display beneath the navigation.

Here is the Javascript inside the html I'm using for the navigation:

```
<script>

function changeNavigation(id) 
{document.getElementById('navigate').innerHTML=document.getElementById(id).innerHTML}

</script>
```

Here is the basis of the navigation menu:

```
<ul>
     <li><a name="marvel" onClick="changeNavigation('marvel')"><span>Marvel Super Hero Squad: Comic Combat</span></a></li>
     <li><a name="kungfupanda2" onClick="changeNavigation('kungfupanda2')"><span>Kung Fu Panda 2</span></a></li>
     <li class='last'><a name="moderngirl" onClick="changeNavigation('moderngirl')"><span>Modern Girl</span></a></li>
  </ul>
```

Here are the navigation "pages" (since the code is long I'll just have the landing page and one other):

```
<div id="navigate">

<!-- Portfolio Landing -->
<div class="portfolio">
<table class="artwork">

<!-- Artwork -->
<tr>
<th>
<img src="C:/Users/Shannon/Desktop/nogoodmonstroddity/Assets/placeholder.png" alt="" />
</th>

<th>
<img src="C:/Users/Shannon/Desktop/nogoodmonstroddity/Assets/placeholder.png" alt="" />
</th>

<th>
<img src="C:/Users/Shannon/Desktop/nogoodmonstroddity/Assets/placeholder.png" alt="" />
</th>

<th>
<img src="C:/Users/Shannon/Desktop/nogoodmonstroddity/Assets/placeholder.png" alt="" />
</th>
</tr>
<!-- Artwork -->

<!-- Descriptions -->
<tr>
<td>
<b>★</b>

<a href="#">
THIS IS PORTFOLIO LANDING
</a>

<b>★</b>
</td>

<td>
<p>
<b>Name of art</b> here is some text about the art and blah blah<br/>
Here is a second line of text.
</p>
</td>

<td>
<p>
Art #3
</p>
</td>

<td>
<p>
Art #4
</p>
</td>

</tr>
<!-- /Descriptions -->

</table>
</div></div>
<!-- /Portfolio Landing -->

<!-- Portfolio Marvel -->
<div style="display:none " id="marvel" class="portfolio">
<table class="artwork">

<!-- Artwork -->
<tr>
<th>
<img src="C:/Users/Shannon/Desktop/nogoodmonstroddity/Assets/placeholder.png" alt="" />
</th>

<th>
<img src="C:/Users/Shannon/Desktop/nogoodmonstroddity/Assets/placeholder.png" alt="" />
</th>

<th>
<img src="C:/Users/Shannon/Desktop/nogoodmonstroddity/Assets/placeholder.png" alt="" />
</th>

<th>
<img src="C:/Users/Shannon/Desktop/nogoodmonstroddity/Assets/placeholder.png" alt="" />
</th>
</tr>
<!-- Artwork -->

<!-- Descriptions -->
<tr>
<td>
<b>★</b>

<a href="#">
THIS IS PORTFOLIO MARVEL
</a>

<b>★</b>
</td>

<td>
<p>
<b>Name of art</b> here is some text about the art and blah blah<br/>
Here is a second line of text.
</p>
</td>

<td>
<p>
Art #3
</p>
</td>

<td>
<p>
Art #4
</p>
</td>

</tr>
<!-- /Descriptions -->

</table>
</div>
<!-- /Portfolio Marvel -->
```

Here are the css classes and another wrapper I'm using for all the content:

```
table.artwork { 
padding: 10px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.portfolio {
overflow-y: hidden;
overflow-x: scroll;
margin-left: 200px;
}

#contentwrapper{
    float: left;
    width: 99%;
    margin: 20px 0px;
}
```

Hope I gave enough info, it's a bit of a specific thing. Thank you for looking!

Comment: Have you tried using the browser's DOM inspector to figure out where the effective styles on the elements are coming from?

Comment: I have, and it's odd because the line
    <div style="display:none " id="marvel" class="portfolio">
doesn't even show up

Comment: If it doesn't show up in the page DOM, then it's not there.  That could be a significant part of the problem.

Comment: It totally was! I actually just figured it out. Posting the solution here because it won't let me answer my own question within 8 hrs after posting it because I'm a new member.

SOLUTION: My script was copying the inner contents, which meant it wasn't copying the attributes from the div. I had to nest another div with the .portfolio class and it worked fine (which is odd, 100% sure I already tried it but I must have fiddled something between now and then)

Answer (score 0):

> SOLUTION: My script was copying the inner contents, which meant it
>   wasn't copying the attributes from the div. I had to nest another div

Instead of nesting elements, you could use [`.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML) instead of [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.innerHTML).

Comment: Oh thank you! I'm not really a fan of nesting because it seems messy.